# Is there a way to practice Tex in Main without publishing my wastebasket?

Tags: support, mathjax

I would like to learn the mathematics scripting protocol (Tex, or whatever). In support of that I would like to be able to do some practice with it in the exact environment it will be used, but I don’t want to do it by the sink-or-swim method of inflicting on the community a posting of mine written in my learning-curve version of the protocol. Is there a venue or functionality for “live, but afterwards discarded” practice?

Comment: You can install latex and play with it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox

Comment: This might be of interest [http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php](http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Comment: AoPS has a TeX rendering system called [TeXeR](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php) which allows you to use the way you'd use yourLaTeX on your computer and even render pdfs. Hope this helps!

Comment: See also: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735)

Answer (score 4):

Combining the references in the comments:

- [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox)
- http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php
- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php

Also, you can go to the "ask new question" page and compose a question, which offers a live as-you-type preview -- just don't ever click "submit question" and you'll be fine.