# MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editor

So right now, to write up a question for Math.StackExchange, I use Firefox to come here, say I'm going to ask a question, and start typing in the box (like I am now). The only way I have to test whether my MathJax markup is correct is to type it here, and see what I get in the preview box. If I'm writing a long question, I have to copy back and forth between here and Notepad, in case I get interrupted.

This seems really klutzy. It's 2012; I should have a better way to test my MathJax input, like a desktop program that interprets MathJax, or a Google Docs application. Can anyone suggest a better approach? Yes, I'm a Windows user, by the way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Somewhat related question on main: [Online MathJaX editor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276104).

Comment: The best way I've found is not writing one.

Comment: VerbTeX LaTeX compiler ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some ideas:

- You can install [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) which has built-in MarkDown / MathJax support
- There are by now (2018!!) lots of MathJax capable MarkDown editors. Personally I use  [Joplin](http://joplin.cozic.net/), I've also tried [Abricotine](https://electronjs.org/apps/abricotine). If you use the Atom editor, the [MarkDown Preview Plus package](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) is useful. (Note: some of these may use KaTeX as the rendering backend instead of MathJax.)
- For an online solution [notepag.es](http://notepag.es/introduction) could work, though for inline math it uses the strange choice of using `%%` as delimiters.

For Mac users, I have heard good things about [Marked](http://markedapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll check them out.

Comment: I went with Qute. notepag.es too mysterious, kramdown and ipython notebook not as easy to install as Qute.

Comment: Minor annoyance with Qute: I would rather use `_…_` for italic, but it forces me to use `*…*`

Comment: Qute and kramdown links are dead now.

Comment: @Ruslan: I edited to put in links to some alive editors. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 14):

I use stackedit now:
https://stackedit.io/

You can sync your files with google drive and dropbox. And there is even real time collaboration support. Quite a decent app.

Answer (score 9):

On the Mac, I use [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) with the following stationery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MathJax</title>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"] }, 
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
        TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } } },
        messageStyle: "none"
    });
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <!-- put your test text here -->
</body>
</html>`
```

Then I fill in the body with my answer/question, save the file with an extension of ".html", and choose "Markup > Preview in BBEdit".

This doesn't pick up the markdown supplied by stackexchange.com, but it renders the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Hmm, I always thought Macs were for artists and writers. (Joke!) I'll consider an iPad next time I'm in the market.

Comment: @MikeC: Unfortunately, BBEdit is not available on the iPad; it requires Mac OS X 10.6 or later.

Answer (score 1):

On the mac I use Macdown:

https://macdown.uranusjr.com/

The only problem I have
is that it sometimes hangs
with a spinning beachball.
It will continue after 10 or more seconds - 
I just have to wait it out.