# How Can I save my answer a draft in MSE?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface

Sometime it happens that I want to  answer a question. But at some point I want to save it for some reason and continue later when I have time or more arguments.

I would like to know how I can  proceed with this in MSE?  thanks

Comment: You can work on your answer [here in the sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/167197). Or personally I use [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/editor).

Comment: I will add that StackEdit is also mentioned among the editors suggested here: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drafts are automatically saved. But only one per type of post (question and answer) and this only for a limited  period of time (a week).

Below the input window you will sometimes see a "Draft saved." Thus if you just want to interrupt your work for a few hours and you *will not use the site in between* this should be fine. Just wait a bit before closing the window.

For details see [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Another option is, as mentioned in the comment, to use [the sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on the meta site. Even if your answer there should be "cleared" you can always retrieve the revision later. A drawback is that your draft is visible to everybody then.

Still another option is to just save your stuff some other place. Copy-paste the text and save it somewhere. If you cannot or do not want to save it on a local device and do not have some space in some 'cloud,'  you could improvise and just use a draft of an email.