# Is it possible to group somehow questions I've asked in the past?

Tags: feature-request

I'm slowly reading through a book, and quite often I ask questions about stuff I don't understand. Because it's taking me a while reading through it sometimes I completely forgot clarified points through the questions I've asked.

Is there a way to group certain questions so it would be easier/quicker for me to look them up?

It doesn't seem a possibility to me, but it would be extremely useful.

Comment: Yes. Keep a list of those in your computer.

Comment: You can't be serious with this comment...

Comment: Why am I not serious? Please, describe *further* your feature request, maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: It means If I have like 20 questions about a specific argument, I think it would be useful to have those in a specific group in my profile. Maybe an additional tab I can create together with "questions/answers/favourites...". The question is 1) is something like this (or similar) something I can do already and I'm not aware of? 2) if not, is something like planned to be an addition at somepoint?

Comment: And I don't understand why it *has to be* on the site, and not off-site. I keep lists of links to questions and answers in an email draft, which makes it easily accessible. If you *really* have to, use your About Me section.

Comment: Because having a list on my computer means I need my computer with me (I access to this site my work computer / my home computer / my smartphone and tablet).... While if it is on the site from wherever I'm a can simply look up the list... How can I use the "about me" section to achieve that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "on your computer", nowadays at least, does not necessarily mean your physical computer. There are clouds like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc, there are email drafts which are fairly accessible, and you can set up a small page on github for free on which you can collect all of the links you want, and more.

Comment: Despite I personally use github, I don't think everyone does... I assume people usually prefer self-contained stuff. But you implicitly/explicitly answered my question anyway (no such feature and no such plan).

Comment: You can check this feature request: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). And also this userscript: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215). (I have to admit that I was unable to get it working - although I did not have too much time to spend with trying it.)

Comment: I've not really used it, but I'm pretty sure you can add your user ID to searches—and that you can find the format for doing that by clicking one of the tags on your profile. It displays search results for your posts with that tag, with the search query visible. Maybe copy the user ID part of the query to somewhere handy for pasting it into searches?

Comment: What about dataexplorer? *(Well, of course the question was about some function inside the userprofile-tabs. But there's no such function)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make do with an existing feature of StackExchange, then as @Asaf suggests in a Comment, the About Me portion of your profile can be so customized.  (Yours is currently empty.)  For example, [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/356647/lee-david-chung-lin) has structured that section of their profile with an outline of Questions asked (it is long enough to require scrolling to view in its entirety).  It demonstrates that MathJax and MarkDown can both be used for this purpose.

You might be interested in something that is only visible to you, but still portable across computers.  The bookmarks feature of Web browsers typically allows you to create a hierarchy of links organized by subject matter (or however you wish), and if you combine that with a Google account, then Chrome/Chromium will synchronize your bookmarks across computers (when you are logged in with that Google account).

For that matter a Gmail account would allow you to keep lists of Question links in a draft email, so that again whenever you are logged into that Google account, you would have convenient access to them.

Comment: I'll stick with the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this procedure and it seems to work OK:

- on your Activity page, go to the *Tags* section and click a tag.
- on the results page, go to the search box that appears near the beginning. Leave the **user:nnnnnn** part as it is. Delete the **[tag]** part and replace it with some suitable search terms , then press Return.

A results page then appears containing just your posts on the topic specified.

I'm not familiar enough with other search features to know whether you can specify that you just want questions rather than all posts, but I'm sure someone else can clarify that.

**Edit:** according to the advanced search tips, you can use **user:me** in a search, which makes getting your user ID unnecessary (but involves more typing than going via a tag).

Comment: If you only want questions, use `is:question` in your search terms.

Comment: Or if you're being efficient, *is:q* does the same thing.

Comment: In fact, if you go to [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current) (or any user's profile for that matter), the `user:xxxxxxx` is already prefilled in the search bar at the top.

Comment: @MartinSleziak You know, I'd never realised that was a search bar! I just interpreted it as a border which happened to have my user ID in it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak In fact, I nearly suggested copying the user ID from there into a search box.

Answer (score 0):

Since also off-site solutions are discussed, I'll add one more. [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) was mentioned a [few times on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stackedit). It is free, but for some payment you can get additional features. (IIRC export to PDF is one of the options unavailable in the free version.) You can find a brief description of this software in the [readme file](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/README.md) in their github repository.

This editor:

- Supports MarkDown + MathJax (i.e., the syntax you are used to).
- Allows to edit existing Markdown files from Google Drive, Dropbox and your local hard drive.

So if you edit your list of questions there, you can have it available in your Google Drive and have easy access to it. I can imagine that making a short list in a format similar to this could be a reasonable solution for your needs. (Just a hypothetical example - I linked to random questions instead, just to have working links. You can basically edit the list any way you want, including some comments etc.)

In fact, I think that having some way of formatting, adding comments, dividing list into sections, etc. makes this actually more useful than just having some list of questions on this site in a format similar [to your favorites](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites). (Of course, the favorites have the advantage that they are on-site and thus they are available more quickly.)

> **My questions about Banach categories**
>
> - [Is every Banach category cartesian closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1)
> - [Completion of semi-Banach category](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2) (The [answer by user12345](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19) contains a useful characterization of semi-Banach categories.)
> - [Abelian Banach category is locally presentable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3). (The [answer by user23456](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30) gives a useful list of references for this topic, especially the book by Potter and Weasley is a must read.)

---

Probably there are also some other solutions where you can use the syntax from Stack Exchange (Markdown+MathJax) and keep the document somewhere online. I will add link to this discussion on meta, which mentions some editors: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735) And you could also have a look at some of the applications listed in [MathJax In Use](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/mathjax-in-use.html) page on the MathJax website. (StackEdit is metnioned there, too.)

I have just tried [mathB.in](http://mathb.in/30897) - however, it has disadvantage that url changes after a new edit. (And I do not have any experience with this page other than the test I did right now.)

Comment: I should add a disclaimer that I haven't actually tried saving things from StackEdit into Google Drive. (But since it is described in the documentation, I suppose it should work.) I have tried this editor a few times - but I have then saved the document locally on my computer. (Maybe users who have more experience with StackEdit can say whether they tried it and whether there were no problems with using this feature.)